# Using ClassicMenu Indicator from Launcher

Tags: xubuntu, 19.10, .desktop, notification-area, xfce-panel

The [ClassicMenu Indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/) works in the *Notification Area* only. But that contains also other notifiers (network, BT) which I prefer to stay at the right of the panel.

If I put the CMI in an own Launcher its icon is shown there but no menu is shown at selecting but a new instance of CMI is created in the *Notification Area* every time.

Is there an option (cmd line or in the `.desktop` or wherever) to use CMI from a Launcher, such being able to place it at the panel's left side?

Comment: You've used `xfce-panel` as a tag. Please [edit] your question to also mention the distribution in use and its version. It maybe relevant. Also, your link indicates that CMI was last updated in 2017.

Comment: I pinged the developer of CMI with a link to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```bash
$ classicmenu-indicator --help
Usage: classicmenu-indicator [options]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -m, --show-menu       Show menu at mouse pointer location. This requires an
                        already running instance of ClassicMenu Indicator
  -i, --ignore-running  Start a new instance of ClassicMenu Indicator, even if
                        there alread is onerunning
```

So:

*Right-Click* panel → *Panel* → *Panel Preferences...* → *Items* → *Launcher* → <kbd>[image]</kbd> (settings) → *General* → **ClassicMenu Indicator** → <kbd>[image]</kbd> (edit) → *Command*: `classicmenu-indicator -m`

in addition to the *Classicmenu-indicator* in the *Notification Area*, which then can be set to ☑ *Hidden* there.

Comment: Maybe I could add an option top avoid the Notification Area icon. https://bugs.launchpad.net/classicmenu-indicator/+bug/1859243